# How to implement rotate and crop together on HTML5 canvas, sequentially?

Tags: image-processing, html5-canvas

The scenario is this. I'm applying `crop` to an image on the canvas, which works well. Now I want to apply `rotate` to it as well. I tried using the browser based css rotation, but it messes up the crop co-ordinates selection as the selected pixels move away with a certain angular displacement. Also eventually I'll have to dump this approach when the time comes to save the final image with the rotation applied.

Currently I'm using a stack to store my cropped stages, which I use for an `undo` functionality to revert to the previous stages. I apply only the last crop from the sequence, which produces the same result as if all the crops were applied.

With rotation, the sequence could be random. I could do:

```
rotate
crop
crop
rotate
rotate
crop
```

How do I apply this sequence? Just apply all of them in an order of occurrence? Which means I'll have to apply all the crops and all the rotations which seems a little inefficient. Also would rotation be just the latest value of the angle, or I'll have to apply the increasing angles along with the crop sequence?

I seriously need a professional advice on this!

Note: Apologies but I can't paste any code samples as it is a very huge code (2000+ lines)! Please don't suggest me any libraries like Pixastic or jCrop as using them with a lot of custom functionality is very dangerous! I prefer writing my own code.

Comment: If you rotate by an angle `a`, and then by an angle `b`, you certainly cannot perform a single rotation at angle `b` in the initial stage and hope to get anything equivalent -- it is required to be `a + b`. If you have a sequence of `k` rotations followed by one crop, you can sum the angles in these `k` rotations and perform a single operation, and only then crop. If you have a sequence of `m` crops without any rotation in the middle, there is no need to do the other crops after the first one. That was all I could take from the question, you have to better describe what you want.

Comment: I'm using a global angle variable hence no issues with increasing/decreasing angles! I just want to know whether I have to apply all the rotates and crops on the original image in order to reach the final stage!

Comment: I believe you completely misunderstood what I commented. It should be clear in which situations you have to apply a rotation (and how to combine more than one), and when you have to crop (and when you can ignore a crop).

Comment: Ahh true that. But since crop and rotate are not the only things I'm doing on my image, there are other pixel level effects I'm doing on it. Every effect needs a canvas redraw, hence whatever state the canvas is in, needs to be reproduced.

Comment: So your question makes no sense now.